# Prinicipal $Gl_n$ bundles, vector bundles and tensor exact functors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

This question is related to [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071213/different-notions-of-torsors-in-algebraic-geometry).

Let $X$ be a scheme over a field $k$ and $G=GL_n$. 
A tensor exact functor 
$$ \omega: Rep_k(GL_n)\to Bun_X $$
is equivalent to a $GL_n$-torsor (as a sheaf) by taking
$$ P:=\underline{Isom}(\omega_{can},\omega) $$
and furthermore this yields a vector bundle
$$  V_1:=P\times^{Gl_n} \Bbb{G}_a^n.$$
On the other hand I can take
$$ V_2:= \omega(k^n,id).$$

**Q:** I think that these two approaches are equivalent, i.e. $V_1\cong V_2$. Is that correct and if so why?

My idea was to prove that equivalently there is an isomorphism of $GL_n$-torsors
$$ P\to \underline{Isom}(\mathcal{O}_X^n,V_2)$$
but I failed to make this isomorphism concrete.